# Getting all the tenants a user belongs to using grah api

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I have an app which uses the AUTH v2 auth provider and the common tenant (login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/) for authentication.

Now, since my users can belong to any AAD tenant, and I want my users to be able to select the tenant in which they are performing operations, I started looking for a way to get all the AAD tenants the logged-in user is part of.

I went through the graph API (graph.microsoft.com) documentation and the closest I could find was this: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_getmemberobjects) but it looks like this operation requires the 'Directory.Read.All' scope which according to graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/permission_scopes requires 'admin consent'.

Is there a way to get all the tenants a logged in user has access to using the graph api, and without requiring admin consent?

Answer (score 2):

This API is not available.  Can you indicate the scenario that requires this API, please? Also please file a request for this feature/API on [uservoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: A possible scenario for this is when you have a multi-tenant application, user x from tenant A is trusted by tenant B. Both tenants use the application. Now the user should be able to switch between the two tenants...