# How can I sign in for a specific tenant in an azure multi-tenant application?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

How can I sign in for specific tenant in a azure multi-tenant application?

I have following scenario:

1. A registered an [Azure Application for multi-tenant scenario](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview) (Web App)
2. Two App Roles “Admin” and “User”
3. Two or more Azure Directories with at least one User. E.g.
4. -- Mary@CompA
5. -- Joe@CompB
6. -- Scott@CompC
7. All these user are assigned in their directory to the “Admin” app role
8. Then I added Mary@CompA to the directories CompB and CompC as a guest user and assign the app role “User”

I can successfully sign in with all users to my application. All the users sign in with their own directory and have “Admin” rights.

But how can I sign in with Mary for tenant/directory CompB or CompC (with “User” rights only)?

Alternatively how can I query all the tenants/directories a user is member of.
In Azure management portal, it is possible for me to switch to a directory, that i'm a member of.

I found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38923520/getting-all-the-tenants-a-user-belongs-to-using-grah-api) that is a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done very easily by modifying the "tenant" endpoint you use for login and token acquisition.

The OAuth 2 endpoint for Azure Active Directory is: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/`

When you are creating a multi-tenant application, you set `{tenant}` to `common` which allows for "tenant discovery". If a user is a member of multiple tenants, it will pick their home tenant as the default login. If you want the user to specifically sign into a different tenant where they are a member, you need to specify that in the `{tenant}` field. You will NOT be able to use common here, so you must have some presumed knowledge of which tenants the user is a part of. This could be as easy as allowing the user to specify their tenant as a part of the login process on your web app.

To put it in the words of your example, for Mary:

- `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/` will sign her into her home tenant, CompA
- `https://login.microsoftonline.com/CompA/oauth2/` will do the same, CompA
- `https://login.microsoftonline.com/CompB/oauth2/` will sign her into CompB as a normal user
- `https://login.microsoftonline.com/CompC/oauth2/` will sign her into CompC as a normal user

I hope this helps!

Comment: Setting {tenant] explicitly worked for me. But now how can I get all tenants that user belongs to? It is possible to request this information on sign-in with oauth (claim)? The signed-in user should either select an active tenant after signing in, or alternatively can switch the tenant on running application (this is e.g. possible in Azure Management Portal)

Comment: It is my understanding that this API is not available publicly. I suggest you allow the user to specify which tenant they would like to sign into.